# Where is "Confirm open after Download" checkbox for file types in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-11

I am attempting to download and save an Excel file. When I navigate to the file in Internet Explorer, it offers me to open the file (which opens it in Excel) or cancel. There use to be a prompt to save or open the file. How can I force that prompt to save the excel file without opening it.

In previous versions of windows you could go to folder options -> File Types and click the advanced button and find an option to Confirm open after download. I can not find this in Windows 7.

As said [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/where-is-confirm-open-after-download-checkbox-for/036e7d8f-50a3-45e5-abd6-7647870b53b2) (similar question) :

Windows 7 does NOT HAVE the "File Types" tab in Folder Options anymore so editing filetypes and ticking the "Confirm open after downloaded" option in Windows 7 is NOT POSSIBLE because it does NOT EXIST.

People also don't understand that this is NOT a problem of filetype association. Filetype association is OK. The problem is that when you click on a file in Internet Explorer, the file is automatically downloaded and opened in a program without the download window opening and showing you options. What we want is to have a window open when we click on a link. That window should have these options: "Open" , "Save" , "Cancel" and an option to "Always ask before opening this type of file".

If you remove the tick from "Always ask before opening this type of file" then next time you download this type of file, the window will not show anymore and the file will download and open automatically. And we want to know how to bring this window back in Windows 7.

Some people say it is possible to do it in registry under "HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows \ Shell \ AttachmentExecute \" but that key is not available in Windows 7 and in some Windows Vista versions so this does NOT WORK. I was not able to find the answer to my problem anywhere so far.

Comment: Can you provide a follow-up on this question? Did you solve the problem, and how?

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found [here](https://jwcooney.com/2014/03/31/remove-internet-explorer-open-or-save-popup/). I tested it like this, with Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7:

1. launched regedit.exe and checked that the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\AttachmentExecute` does not exist
2. closed the registry editor
3. opened Internet Explorer
4. visited a url where there is a .xlsx file
5. saved the file (clicked on `Save`)
6. pressed `CTRL+J` to open the download window
7. right clicked the downloaded .xls file
8. unselected "Always ask before opening this type of file"
9. visited the same .xlsx url again: this time the file opened automatically
10. closed Internet Explorer and its Download window
11. launched regedit.exe and checked that the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\AttachmentExecute\{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` does now exist, and contains a `Excel.Sheet.12` REG_NONE value
12. deleted the value and closed the registry editor
13. launched Internet Explorer and visited the same .xlsx url a third time: now I am being presented with the same `Open, Save, Save with name` choice as when I started

Steps 1-9 are for reproducing the issue you describe, to solve it you should follow steps 10-13.

Comment: Does not work on my machine.